# Reverse engineering apps for Windows Phone 7 and 8

Tags: windowsphone

How can I reverse engineer Windows Phone apps? Especially apps that are running on version 7.8 and 8 of the OS?

I'm looking for tools and procedures for doing this.

Answer (score 9):

If you have the XAP file, it is just a ZIP format. You can rename it and open it.

If you don't have the XAP file, you can use XGENO to get it - http://mktwp7.codeplex.com/

To decompile the DLLs, use DotPeek.

Comment: Am I correct that these no longer work with wp8, as the xap files are now encrypted?

Comment: You know, I haven't tried.  Are they indeed encrypted? Win8 apps are supposed to be encrypted too, and they sure aren't.