# Is it possible to Reverse engineer digitally signed Windows Phone 8 apps (WP8 APPS)?

Tags: windowsphone

I have researched a lot about reverse engineering WP8 apps but nothing seems to work for apps that are digitally signed (Yes, I am talking about Apps from Windows App Store)

XAPSpy works with Windows Phone 7 only and may be, with unsigned WP8 apps(but I am not sure on this part).

Some answers of StackExchange says that `Tangerine` and `Windows Phone App Analyzer` can be used, but it doesn't seem to work with digitally signed apps.

`Question` :

Is it not possible at all, to reverse engineer WP8 apps collected from Store and perform security audit? 
TIA.

Regards,

Comment: i think xap files are encrypted, so my guess is you would need to root/jailbreak the phone first, and then run the app under a debugger to be able to decrypt it.

Comment: but maybe the decryption is handled at installation time, in that case,  you might be able to find the decrypted apps in a device backup.

Comment: Willem - The marketplace apps are digitally signed and PlayDRM encrypted.
The "root/jailbreak" solution is true but as per my knowledge the jailbreak is not yet available for Windows Phone 8.

I have been searching since long and have come to the conclusion that currently my question has no solution unless any jailbreak is available or else the device has a zero-day ;-). 
The only solution left is to get the Developer version of the app in order to proceed further.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse engineering apps for Windows Phone 7 and 8](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274/reverse-engineering-apps-for-windows-phone-7-and-8)

Comment: David - Thank you Sir, but this no more works. I already came across this question during my research. 
You can read the first comment to that question. It is true, I tried it.
New formats come encrypted and can't be simply renamed and opened.